# How to remove element with id and class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know how to select element by Id and how to select element by class but I am confused about how to get the element id after

```
document.getElementsByClassName('remove').click(function(){})


<div id='wrapper'> 
  <ul id='main−list'>
    <li> Value 1
      <div class='remove' id='1'>remove</div> 
    </ li>
      ....
    <li>
      Value 100
      <div class='remove' id='100'>remove</div> 
    </ li>
  </ ul> 
</ div>
```

Write a javascript that removes the relevant list item from the page when the remove element is clicked. You may use the jQuery library if you choose.

Comment: You haven't shown what you've tried. Also, get rid of the "smart" quotes (i.e. `’remove’`) and use "straight" quotes (unformatted) as in: `'remove'`.

Comment: Also, I think your instructions are worded incorrectly. If the item is removed, you can't click on it. The assignment should be *"Write a JavaScript that removes a list item from the page when the element is clicked"*

Comment: There has got to be 100 & 1 examples of doing something like this with jQuery..  Did your search really return nothing?.

Comment: And, for the love of God, please ask your instructor to only teach you to use JQuery for things that are difficult to do without it. This is a simple DOM manipulation that, in no way, justifies JQuery usage.

Comment: And note that your `id`s for `wrapper` and `main-list` include a space at the end of them, which is invalid and will cause issues for you.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` returns a live node list. You can't call `.click()` on a node list. You have to call it on a node.

Comment: this part `You may use the jQuery library if you choose` seems more of an instruction than asking for help/suggestions. you can try to look up for `.closest()`

Comment: @guradio If you are using JQuery, you don't need `.closest()`.

Comment: And, your closing tags are incorrect. There should not be any spaces in them.

Comment: @ScottMarcus  I personally don't use jQuery anymore,.  but `.closest("li")` would seem a good fit, so if using jquery why not?

Comment: @Keith Because the assignment isn't to remove the nearest ancestor. It's to remove the clicked element (hint: `this`).

Comment: @ScottMarcus  So you think the assignment is to remove the button (div), but not the li, you may be right but that's just silly..

Comment: @ScottMarcus i must agree wil Keith on this one. Removing a button doesnt make sense at all. anyway it just my assumption.

Comment: Are you paying for this school?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this jQuery function.
It will remove each item based on which 'li' do you click.

```
$("li").click(function() { 
   $(this).remove(); 
});
```

Comment: Please don't supply answers to poor questions. It just encourages more of the same. Questions should be accompanied by some sort of attempt at a solution. All you've done here is the OP's homework for him/her.